# Sort a list efficiently which contains only 0 and 1 without using any builtin python sort function?

Tags: python

What is the most efficient way to sort a list, `[0,0,1,0,1,1,0]` whose elements are only `0` & `1`, without using any builtin `sort()` or `sorted()` or `count()` function. O(n) or less than that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
>>> l, s = len(lst), sum(lst)
>>> result = [0] * (l - s) + [1] * s
>>> result
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many different general sorting algorithms that can be used. However, in this case, the most important consideration is that all the elements to sort belong to the set (0,1).

As other contributors answered there is a trivial implementation.

```
def radix_sort(a):
    slist = [[],[]]
    for elem in a:
        slist[elem].append(elem)
    return slist[0] + slist[1]

print radix_sort([0,0,1,0,1,1,0])
```

It must be noted that this is a particular implementation of the [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). And this can be extended easily if the elements of the list to be sorted belong to a defined limited set.

```
def radix_sort(a, elems):
    slist = {}
    for elem in elems:
        slist[elem] = []
    for elem in a:
        slist[elem].append(elem)
    nslist = []
    for elem in elems:
        nslist += slist[elem]
    return nslist

print radix_sort([2,0,0,1,3,0,1,1,0],[0,1,2,3])
```

No `sort()` or `sorted()` or `count()` function. O(n)

Comment: Please, don't shade the builtin functions or data types (`id` and `set` in your case)

Answer (score 2):

This one is `O(n)` (you can't get less):

```
old = [0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
zeroes = old.count(0) #you gotta count them somehow!
new = [0]*zeroes + [1]*(len(old) - zeroes)
```

As there are no Python loops, this may be the faster you can get in pure Python...

Comment: `count_of_ones = sum(old)` :)

Comment: `.count()` is 15% faster (for me). Use the `timeit` module and see for yourself.

Comment: @Blender that's what I was going to say :)

Comment: Tested this solution as well as all the others. It's currently the fastest.

Comment: @Blender, `data = [0,1] * 10000`, 1000 iterations: `sum(data)` - 0.561300992966, `data.count(0)` - 0.661532878876

Comment: @astynax: I'd be careful with that syntax. It doesn't do what you think it does when initializing `data`.

Comment: @astynax Interesting. In Python 2.x it's true for large lists but on Python 3.x (where I was testing), it is not true probably because of the new `int` type which is like the old `long` type.

Comment: BTW, I'm 10x evil (6660)... Just for the record ;)

Comment: @Blender, `[0,1] * 10000 = [0,1,0,1,0,1....]`. This syntax safe if the list contains only immutable objects (like `1` and `0`) :)

Comment: @JBernardo, I tested this with Python 2.7 :)

Comment: @Blender @asyntax Checking the python source code, the `.count` method calls the `PyObject_RichCompareBool` function. With **big** lists of only zeroes and lists of only ones, the timing fluctuates a lot (from 0.3 to 2 secs), while with `sum` it does not. Maybe this function is doing some funky stuff.

Comment: Oh, of course... The `PyObject_RichCompareBool` checks for identity and only then for value. That's the behavior on `dict` retrieval as well.

Answer (score 1):

`def sort_arr_with_zero_one():`

```
  main_list = [0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
  zero_list = []
  one_list = []
  for i in main_list:
    if i:
        one_list.append(i)
    else:
        zero_list.append(i)

  return zero_list + one_list
```

Comment: I selected astynax's answer as the one since it has more vote. But i was able to understand yours much easily than any others. And even you didn't use sort , sorted or count. and i think its o(n) too. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have only two values, so you know in advance the precise structure of the output: it will be divided into two regions of varying lengths.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this:

```
b = [0,0,1,0,1,1,0]

def odd_sort(a):
  zeroes = a.count(0)

  return [0 for i in xrange(zeroes)] + [1 for i in xrange(len(a) - zeroes)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could walk the list with two pointers, one from the start (`i`) and from the end (`j`), and compare the values one by one and swap them if necessary:

```
def sort_binary_values(l):
    i, j = 0, len(l)-1
    while i < j:
        # skip 0 values from the begin
        while i < j and l[i] == 0:
            i = i+1
        if i >= j: break
        # skip 1 values from the end
        while i < j and l[j] == 1:
            j = j-1
        if i >= j: break
        # since all in sequence values have been skipped and i and j did not reach each other
        # we encountered a pair that is out of order and needs to be swapped
        l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]
        j = j-1
        i = i+1
    return l
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer by JBernado, but will throw in another monstrous option (although I've not done any profiling on it - it's not particulary extensible as it relies on the order of a dictionary hash, but works for 0 and 1):

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
from collections import Counter

list(chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, *zip(*Counter(bits).items()))))
```

**Or - slightly less convoluted...**

```
from itertools import repeat, chain, islice, ifilter
from operator import not_

list(islice(chain(ifilter(not_, bits), repeat(1)), len(bits)))
```

This should keep everything at the C level - so it should be fairly optimal.

Comment: It's worth noting that the first code block will work with any ints (at least in CPython where hash(int) == int), but the second is purely 0/1

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know is how long the original sequence is and how many ones are in it.

```
old = [0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
ones = sum(1 for b in old if b)
new = [0]*(len(old)-ones) + [1]*ones
```

Comment: Do you really want to be generating a list to get its length. It may be better written as `sum(1 for i in old if i)`

Comment: @Jon Clements: Yeah, that's even better. Answer updated -- thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a Python solution in O(n) time and O(2) space.

Absolutely no need to create new lists and best time performance

```
def sort01(arr):
  i = 0
  j = len(arr)-1
  while i < j:
    while arr[i] == 0:
      i += 1
    while arr[j] == 1:
      j -= 1
    if i<j:
      arr[i] = 0
      arr[j] = 1
  return arr
```